# On the automorphism group of the quotient power series over 1 variable $\mathbb{F}_p((t))$.

Tags: power-series, finite-fields, automorphism-group

Let $\mathbb{F}_p$ be the finite field with $p$ (prime) elements. What is the group of (continuous) field automorphisms
$$
\text{Aut}(\mathbb{F}_p((t)))?
$$
If I am not mistaken, then
$$
\text{Aut}(\mathbb{F}_p[[t]])
$$
should consist of those maps $\varphi$ given by
$$
\varphi(t) \in t \cdot \mathbb{F}^{\times}_p + t^2 \cdot \mathbb{F}_p[[t]]
$$
or something like that. Question is, how big can the former become?

**Comment:** It is not really something that I need for my research, it is just a curiosity.

Comment: It’s been  while since I thought about these things specifically. But as I recall, every automorphism of a power-series field over a finite field is continuous. And it should be that the groups  of automorphisms of the power-series ring and its fraction-field are the same. Let’s see whether someone who’s surer of themself weighs in on the issue.

Comment: I know the statement for local fields of characteristic $0$; I had a feeling that it might be the case for char $> 0$ too, but am (was) not sure. I saw though, that the Nottingham group is the subgroup of $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{F}_p((t))$ consisting of wild automorphisms, so somebody for sure studied it already.

Comment: Yes, you have correctly identified the full automorphism group as all series $\sum_{i>0}c_it^i$ with $c_1\ne0$; the so-called Nottingham group consists of those with $c_1=1$. Group action is substitution of series… The story is more complicated for bigger fields than $\Bbb F_p$, ’cause then you have to take account of the automorphisms of the constant field.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Lubin! How sure are you about $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{F}_p((t))) = \text{Aut}(\mathbb{F}_p[[t]])$? If at some point you come across a reference, feel free to share it.

Comment: Let me call $\Bbb F_p=k$. I think it falls out of the fact that every automorphism of $k((t))$ is continuous. Let $\varphi$ be a (continuous) automorphism of the above field; in this field, $t$ is “topologically nilpotent”, i.e. its powers go to zero. Thus $\varphi(t)$ must be top.nilp., i.e. in $t\in tk[[t]]$, the maximal ideal of $k[[t]]$. The initial degree must be $1$, because for $g(t)\in k[[[t]]$ with initial degree $n$, the field extension degree $[k((t)):k((g))]$ is equal to $n$.

Comment: Thanks Lubin, I had actually thought about it but I still was asking myself why e.g. $t \mapsto t^{-1}$ does not get you an automorphism of $k((t))$ that is not continuous? That was silly from me, I think I just imagined the elements of $k((t))$ the wrong way I kind of wrongly assumed that $k[[t,t^{-1}]]$ would lie inside $k((t))$. Now it is way clearer for me.